# Reserving the edge of the screen in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

How can I make a window (such as a `java.awt.Frame`, `javax.swing.JFrame`, `java.awt.Dialog`, `javax.swing.JDialog`, etc.) reserve the edge of the screen, like a dock, taskbar, Trillian, or Microsoft OneNote can? I aim to only use standard JDK libraries if possible.

Comment: Would `JSplitPane` do? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to create window that behaviors like tool bar on windows desktop?

Comment: @trashgod: `javax.swing.JSplitPane` will not do; it is a component that only works within a window

Comment: It is a good question. I also wanted to find how to do this. Unfortunately I do not know.

Comment: You can use the default toolkit to get the resolution, and create an undecorated, unresizable, unmovable frame. I don't believe you can 'reserve' screen space however, sounds like thats a bit too display-manager specific for java.

Comment: I know I can, and can't that just be a `native` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is very specific to the Windows operating system, and as such there is no way to do this in the standard JDK or with AWT/Swing, since these need to work consistently across a number of different operating systems.

The closest equivalent to what you want is to get the current screen's boundaries and move/resize your window to fit flush against one side, although this will now have any effect on the desktop or other windows.

The closest thing you will probably get to what you want is by using [JNIWrapper and WinPack](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/) to alter the native window behaviour.  Their documentation doesn't show anything about desktop toolbars, though.  You would probably have to use their JNI to access the specific COM functions directly and then find out how to do it in C++, but if you don't know C++, that's probably out of the scope of your project.

Addendum:

If you want to make use of the native features for specific operating systems and desktop managers, you will need to connect with a *native* C++ library to hook into Gnome, KDE, Mac OS etc.  Search for 'Java JNI' and the windowing system you want to integrate with to find packages you can use.  For instance, for Gnome, see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libjava-gnome-jni).

If you want to support multiple operating systems, make sure you create a common interface so you can make implementations that connect with the respective JNIs depending on which one is available at runtime, and allow fallback if none of them are available.

PS. If you want popup notifications in your app, Mac OS and various Linux builds support Growl so that can save you some time.

Comment: I was afraid of that u.u   Why can't other OSs have all of Windows' capabilities? :c

Comment: Well, for a start, if all OSs had all the same features, there would be no choice for consumers.  Also, we need to remember that Java isn't designed only for PCs, but also runs on mobile phones, security systems and other embedded devices that may have very limited display capabilities, or none at all.  Sun/Oracle can't write native code to support all possible hardware and software configurations.  That's where you have to find a JNI that does what you want, or write one yourself.  I'm guessing you'll have to go for the simple solution - move & resize your application window.

Comment: Wait... But OS X can reserve the top for the menu bar and other sides for the dock, Gnome and Unity can do the same... why is this OS-specific?

Comment: Yes, all those native features are specific to their respective OS. There's no 'why' about it - that's just how it is. They are completely different software systems, developed by different people. I'm going to expand my original answer a little because it's too long for this comment.

Comment: Thank you. For notifications, I just place an icon in the notification area and have it push notifications to the OS, which tend to render as text balloons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets() From JMenu sources

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle screenBounds = new Rectangle(toolkit.getScreenSize());
    GraphicsEnvironment ge =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    for(int i = 0; i < gd.length; i++) {
        if(gd[i].getType() == GraphicsDevice.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN) {
            GraphicsConfiguration dgc =
                gd[i].getDefaultConfiguration();
            if(dgc.getBounds().contains(position)) {
                gc = dgc;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    if (gc != null) {
        screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
        // take screen insets (e.g. taskbar) into account
        Insets screenInsets = toolkit.getScreenInsets(gc);

        screenBounds.width -= 
                    Math.abs(screenInsets.left + screenInsets.right);
        screenBounds.height -= 
                    Math.abs(screenInsets.top + screenInsets.bottom);
        position.x -= Math.abs(screenInsets.left);
        position.y -= Math.abs(screenInsets.top);
    }
```

Comment: also, running this method doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: It's just a snippet of code how the insets are obtained in JMenu. Use the same approach. You can get default toolkit and pass GraphicsConfiguration in the getScreenInsets() method. You'll get the insets and use them subtracting from screen bounds,

Comment: Tat doesn't modify the actual screen bounds, just the local copy