# How to stick Java Application to top of screen

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, toolkit

I've been searching around quite a bit and haven't been able to find any details on how to accomplish what I'm attempting to do. I would like my Java application to "snap/mount/stick" to the top of the screen so that anything opened up after it (for example, power point) would only use the remaining space instead of the entire screen when maximized.

I'm not even sure if it is possible, but if it is could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean similar to what the magnifier does in Windows accessibility tools?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I think he means something like the Apple menu bar that's on top always, and all other applications will use only the remaining space. @Flynn1179

Comment: @user1394965 by default you are right setModal or ModalityTypes block/works only for Top-Level Containers from current JVM instance,

Comment: @Aniket This is also a good example (the two accomplish the same goal)

Comment: Similar question (might be a duplicate, I'm not sure): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660102/reserving-the-edge-of-the-screen-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using standard Java features - only with some native code assistance which should be able to modify other applications behavior, so that they pack themselves into the remaining screen "space". But you will have to code that native part for each OS you want to support. And also you will have to call those native features from Java using JNI. And also some application might act unexpectedly when you will try to modify their size.

Anyway, its a bad idea to do such a "feature" in your Java application - you will have a lot of headache supporting it in future.